# How to add onClick event in helpertext Material UI TextField?

Tags: material-ui

Is possible to add `onClick` event in `helperText` Material UI `TextField`? And can I add 2 `helperText` in 1 `TextField`?

```js
<TextField
 variant="outlined"
 placeholder="Write a comment..."
 fullWidth
 multiline
 className={classes.tfCmt}
 onChange={this.handleAddComment}
 onFocus={this.handleAppearSaveBtn}
 helperText={visibleSaveBtn && "Save"}
 FormHelperTextProps={{
  className: classes.btnAction
 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is possible to add onClick event in helpertext Material UI TextField?

Yes. You could include an `onClick` function on your `FormHelperTextProps`.

```js
...
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  placeholder="Write a comment..."
  fullWidth
  multiline
  helperText="Hello world"
  FormHelperTextProps={{
    onClick: () => alert("Clicked!")
  }}
/>
```

> And can I add 2 helptext in 1 TextField?

If I understand correctly, you want to have 2 elements for helper text. You could create a component and pass that as your `helperText` prop to `TextField` component.

```js
...
function HelperTexts() {
  const helperTexts = [
    {
      id: 1,
      value: "helper text 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: "helper text 2"
    }
  ];

  return helperTexts.map((text) => (
    <span key={text.id} data-id={text.id} className="helper-text">
      {text.value}
    </span>
  ));
}

return (
  <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    placeholder="Write a comment..."
    fullWidth
    multiline
    helperText={<HelperTexts />}
  />
);
```

[image: Edit friendly-greider-iyvkz]

Comment: Great. Thank you so much